# About animated video makers not video editors

Tags: software-recommendation, video, animations

Are there any professional applications for making animated videos on Ubuntu 16.04? Please suggest the most reliable ones, also those which may cost money. I found the free ones are not working well.

I found VideoMakerFx working awesome for me. But that's only compatible for windows and mac.

Comment: If you list the ones you tried and did not like, it will prevent people from wasting their time by suggesting those.

Comment: I tried free ones. Please suggest applications like VideoMakerFx.........